# How to enable Email Recipients to reply to all?

Tags: email

When you send an email (not a mailing) to the members of a Group, they all receive it in BCC, which makes it impossible for them to reply to all.

How can I change (or parameterize) that ? Is there any existing Extension ?

Answer (score 1):

We've run into the same issue, and couldn't find any extension to solve it.

We could develop something like a 'recipients public' flag on the "Email - send now" action, that would allow the reply-all option to work in any email client.

Is anyone else interested in this development? Let us know...

Comment: When you use the cc field they are sent as regular cc. I know the search dropdown action doesn't have that option right now, but it seems like adding that task option would be another way. I.e. if the actions dropdown had "Email - send as CC".